# Edited messages in python-telegram-bot wrapper

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Using the python-telegram-bot wrapper, I'm trying to have my bot print some text if it receives a message, then print some other text if it's edited.

However I can only have 1 of the following:
if I use

```
update.message.reply_text("Original")
```

It prints 'Original' successfully. However if bot receives a msg with the following code:

```
update.edited_message.reply_text("Edited")
update.message.reply_text("Original")
```

It does not print 'Original' but will only print 'Edited' once the message is edited.

If I put the update.message.reply_text first, it will print "Original" but will not print "Edited" when the message is edited

So basically whichever statement is first, only that is executed. Is there anyway around this?
Thanks any help would be greatly appreciated

P.S here is my full code
https://pastebin.com/mS6Y98x1

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I fixed it by creating 2 functions, then put the dispatch handler of the edit function after the normal message function.